# Where is pithos installed?

Tags: python, search

I'm trying to find the installation directory in Pithos so I can hack it, and am really bad a unix commands and am embarrassed to ask this.  If I do:

```
`which pithos`
```

This returns a link to the script installed in `/usr/bin`, but doesn't show me where all of the pithos source files are.  What is the best way to do something like this?

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Contents-amd64.gz is a funny thing, I suggest to google for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, python package source files are located in `/usr/lib/python<version>/site-packages`. There's more information about this in the python docs:

- https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path
- https://docs.python.org/2/install/#how-installation-works

Comment: You're right.  I'm an idiot and didn't realize it would install as a normal python package; thought there was something more to it.

Answer (score 1):

Where the packages gets installed heavily depends on the system configuration  `/usr/lib/python<version>/site-packages` is a good candidate but doesn't always exists, sometimes this is `/usr/lib/python<version>/dist-packages` or `/usr/local/lib/python<version>/site-packages` etc.

The generic way if you have found the pithos script is to locate the files it is importing. You can use `locate` for that if you have that installed, or `find / modulename.py`, but quite often it is quicker to start up python and then do (adapting the module name to import to the ones imported in the script):

```
>>> import pithos
print pithos.__file__
```