# How Troubleshoot Failed Installation of pywfdb from pip?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, python, pip, virtualenv

Condition: unable to troubleshoot failed installation of the library/module `pywfdb` from `pip`
Differential conditions: failed dependenciens of `pywfdb`
Exclude: `upstart`/`systemd` design bugs with `runit` in Ubuntu [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284453/16920) since Ubuntu  >=14.10
Settings

- PATH `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`
- PYTHONPATH blank in `$HOME/.bashrc`

Work flow for dependencies and dirty installation with much logs

- Edwinksl's proposal: `sudo apt-get install python-pyrex`

  ```
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree
  Reading state information... Done
  The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-pyrex
  0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.         2 not fully installed or removed.
  Need to get 181 kB of archives.
  After this operation, 996 kB of additional disk space will be used.
  Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python-pyrex all 0.9.8.5-2.1ubuntu1 [181 kB]
  Fetched 181 kB in 0s (356 kB/s)      
  Selecting previously unselected package python-pyrex.
  (Reading database ... 434011 files and directories currently installed.)
  Preparing to unpack .../python-pyrex_0.9.8.5-2.1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
  Unpacking python-pyrex (0.9.8.5-2.1ubuntu1) ...
  Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.7) ...
  Processing 1 added doc-base file...
  Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
  Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
  Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
  - -
  Setting up python-pyrex (0.9.8.5-2.1ubuntu1) ...
  - -
  ```
- Work flow with dirty installation to not clean up after the install, to see what `pip` was trying to do `sudo -H pip install --no-clean pywfdb`

  ```
  Collecting pywfdb
    Using cached pywfdb-0.1.1.zip
  Building wheels for collected packages: pywfdb
    Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pywfdb ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-_Tu9q1/pywfdb/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpemnpLdpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pywfdb
    copying pywfdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pywfdb
    copying pywfdb/ecgcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pywfdb
    package init file 'example/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pywfdb/example
    copying example/readinfo.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pywfdb/example
    copying example/plot.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pywfdb/example
    running build_ext
    building 'pywfdb._pywfdb' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pywfdb
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/wfdb-10.4.4
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/wfdb-10.4.4/lib
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I./wfdb-10.4.4/lib -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c pywfdb/_pywfdb.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pywfdb/_pywfdb.o -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unused
    pywfdb/_pywfdb.c:15:22: fatal error: ecgcodes.h: No such file or directory
    #include "ecgcodes.h"
                          ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
    Failed building wheel for pywfdb
    Running setup.py clean for pywfdb
    Failed to build pywfdb
   Installing collected packages: pywfdb
   Running setup.py install for pywfdb ... error
      Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-_Tu9q1/pywfdb/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-gdKcwF-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pywfdb
      copying pywfdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pywfdb
      copying pywfdb/ecgcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pywfdb
      package init file 'example/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pywfdb/example
      copying example/readinfo.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pywfdb/example
      copying example/plot.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pywfdb/example
      running build_ext
      building 'pywfdb._pywfdb' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pywfdb
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/wfdb-10.4.4
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/wfdb-10.4.4/lib
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I./wfdb-10.4.4/lib -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c pywfdb/_pywfdb.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pywfdb/_pywfdb.o -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unused
      pywfdb/_pywfdb.c:15:22: fatal error: ecgcodes.h: No such file or directory
      #include "ecgcodes.h"
                           ^
      compilation terminated.
      error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

      ----------------------------------------
      Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-_Tu9q1/pywfdb/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-gdKcwF-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_Tu9q1/pywfdb/
  ```

Open

- **Why *Failed building wheel for pywfdb*?**
- Why the following error reproduced here from the full log?

  ```
  Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-_Tu9q1/pywfdb/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-gdKcwF-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_Tu9q1/pywfdb/
  ```

### Troubleshooting  Methods

Pip local modules where you see no `wfdb` found got by Adam's first command set

```
" https://stackoverflow.com/a/23885252/54964 "
['adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4', 'alabaster==0.7.8', 'auxlib==0.0.37', 'babel==2.3.4', 'backports-abc==0.4', 'backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0', 'backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1', 'beautifulsoup4==4.4.1', 'ccsm==0.9.12.2', 'certifi==2016.2.28', 'chardet==2.3.0', 'compizconfig-python==0.9.12.2', 'configparser==3.5.0', 'cycler==0.10.0', 'decorator==4.0.9', 'docutils==0.12', 'duplicity==0.7.6', 'entrypoints==0.2.2', 'enum34==1.1.6', 'functools32==3.2.3.post2', 'futures==3.0.5', 'html5lib==0.999', 'httplib2==0.9.1', 'imagesize==0.7.1', 'ipykernel==4.3.1', 'ipyparallel==5.0.1', 'ipython-genutils==0.1.0', 'ipython==4.2.0', 'ipywidgets==5.1.5', 'jinja2==2.8', 'jsonschema==2.5.1', 'jupyter-client==4.2.2', 'jupyter-core==4.1.0', 'lockfile==0.12.2', 'lxml==3.5.0', 'markupsafe==0.23', 'matlab-kernel==0.9.6', 'matplotlib==1.5.1', 'metakernel==0.13.0', 'mistune==0.7.2', 'nbconvert==4.2.0', 'nbformat==4.0.1', 'nose==1.3.7', 'notebook==4.2.1', 'numpy==1.11.0', 'pandas==0.18.1', 'path.py==8.2.1', 'pathlib2==2.1.0', 'pdfshuffler==0.6.0', 'pexpect==4.1.0', 'pickleshare==0.7.2', 'pillow==3.1.2', 'pip==8.1.2', 'ptyprocess==0.5.1', 'pycosat==0.6.1', 'pycurl==7.43.0', 'pygments==2.1.3', 'pygobject==3.20.0', 'pyicu==1.9.2', 'pymatbridge==0.5.2', 'pymysql==0.7.2', 'pyparsing==2.1.4', 'pypdf==1.13', 'python-dateutil==2.5.3', 'python-djvulibre==0.7', 'pytz==2016.4', 'pyxdg==0.25', 'pyyaml==3.11', 'pyzmq==15.2.0', 'qtconsole==4.2.1', 'requests==2.10.0', 'scour==0.32', 'setuptools==22.0.5', 'simplegeneric==0.8.1', 'singledispatch==3.4.0.3', 'six==1.10.0', 'snowballstemmer==1.2.1', 'sphinx==1.4.3', 'subprocess32==3.2.6', 'terminado==0.6', 'testpath==0.3', 'tornado==4.3', 'traitlets==4.2.1', 'unity-lens-photos==1.0', 'wheel==0.29.0', 'widgetsnbextension==1.2.3']
```

Unsuccessful test commands for the info of the package/module/library

- `pip search wfdb` gives `pywfdb (0.1.1)  - Python interface to WFDB library` so I expect it to include also the module which you can `import`.
- `find /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages -name '*wfdb*'` returns blank.
- `pip list |grep wfdb` returns blank.
- `pip show pywfdb` returns blank.

Test code which shows that the module is not found

```
" http://www.pybytes.com/pywfdb/ "
import pywfdb
```

Trying to search the module

- Not installed as normal python package because not in `/usr/lib/python<version>/site-packages` as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182080/16920); I searched all directories (`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/` and `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/`).
- Not in `dist-packages` based on the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184191/16920).  Command `ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ | grep wfdb` returns blank.
- `>>> import site; site.getsitepackages()` gives the output

  ```
  ['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
  ```

  Blank outputs for `ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages | grep wfdb` and `ls /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages | grep wfdb`.

System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.6
Linux kernel options: wl
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid
Python: 2.7.11+
Pip: latest (8.1.2) `pip install --upgrade pip` returns `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /home/masi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
Latest pip [modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3452888/54964): `pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U` done before
Bash: 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Can you get the package if you install it inside a `virtualenv`?  In a virtualenv you're free from ubuntu's package manager.  Also `find /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages -name '*wfdb*'` should be more effective than plain `ls`

Comment: Are you sure it installed successfully?

Comment: Well, if tests do not pass in `setup.py` it will not install the module.  `Pyrex` is a wrapper for C code, and the underlying `wfdb` library is in C code, therefore i suspect you do not have `wfdb` installed.

Comment: You can follow either the installation guide provided by [pywfdb](http://www.pybytes.com/pywfdb/) or the one provided by [wfdb itself](https://www.physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb-linux-quick-start.shtml)

Comment: @Masi Try `sudo apt install python-pyrex` and then `sudo -H pip install pywfdb` and see if that resolves the `ImportError`.

Comment: Stop ignoring errors!  You created a snowball of errors that you cannot get out off.  Your first problem is that *there is something wrong with upstart*.  Fix that first, then update `apt-get` as far as you can and test if it works, only then go for installing new stuff.

Comment: You need a running `dpkg`, without a running `dpkg`/`apt-get` your system is neigh useless.  And i mean the part about "ignoring errors" until you have `Pyrex` and `wfdb` you will not be able to install `pywfdb`.  Errors must be fixed bottom up, otherwise they will keep biting.

Comment: Fair enough, it is worth a try.  You can setup a `virtualenv` and install `Pyrex` and then try `pywfdb` (I assume you are 100% you have the `wfdb` lib installed).  Yet, `Pyrex` must be compiled, if the compiler tree is not OK you're dead in boots and your only option is to fix `dpkg`.  Also, *ul.SE* will suggest in a moment to move this to `/dev/chat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the above answer, since it pointed me in the right direction but skipped a few keysteps.

Disclaimer: I am not an experienced Linux user, but this worked on a clean DigitalOcean Ubuntu install.

1. depencies (in case you haven't already):

   - `$ sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip python-pyrex unzip`
2. download WFDB source from `www.physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb.tar.gz`

   - extract to `~/`
3. Compile and install the WFDB C library

   - `@~/wfdb-10.5.24/wfdb$ ./configure --without-netfiles --static --static_only`
   - (the tutorial at http://www.pybytes.com/pywfdb/ says you need to use `--without-netfiles` switch; <strike>i didn't have any problems by *not* using it, but couldn't get the python wrapper to import from physionet</strike> and so you should)
   - `@~/wfdb-10.5.24/wfdb$ sudo make install`
   - `@~/wfdb-10.5.24/wfdb$ make check`
4. download pywfdb source from `pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pywfdb/pywfdb-0.1.1.zip`

   - unzip to `~/`
5. edit `~/pywfdb-0.1.1/pywfdb/_pywfdb.c`

   - replace `\*.h` with `<wfdb/*.h>` in lines 15, 16, 17
6. edit `~/pywfdb-0.1.1/setup.py`

   - replace `./wfdb-10.4.4/` with `/home/username/wfdb-10.5.24/` in lines 14, 15 (or wherever you extracted it to; the `~/` alias did not work for me)
7. `@/usr/include$ ln -s /usr/local/include/wfdb wfdb`
8. `@~/pywfdb$ sudo python setup.py install`
9. (above answer ends here, but I needed this extra step to actually import the lib within python) `@/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages$ ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pywfdb pywfdb`

Comment: It would be great if you can also include xenith's proposal in your answer as one solution. I really like your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Masi,

finally I could run this library. My steps are as follows:

1. download `wfdb-10.5.24` from physionet website
2. compile and install
3. ```
   cd /usr/include
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/include/wfdb wfdb
   ```
4. `sudo apt-get install python-pyrex`
5. open this file by any text editor `pywfdb/_pywfdb.c` and replace these lines into:

   ```
   #include <wfdb/ecgcodes.h>
   #include <wfdb/ecgmap.h>
   #include <wfdb/wfdb.h>
   ```
6. in `setup.py` file on lines 14 and 15 put the path of `wfdb-10.5.24/lib` directory
7. `python setup.py install`

Linux: Ubuntu 16.04